# Paypal no rules triggered error

Tags: paypal

I've been working with payflow sandbox for 3 days now. I downloaded the paypalfunctions.php from payflow integration wizard. My problem now is that paypal result always return No Rules Triggered. How can I fix it?

Here is the code I downloaded from their integration wizard

```
    Defines all the global variables and the wrapper functions 
    ********************************************/
    $PROXY_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
    $PROXY_PORT = '808';

    $Env = "pilot";//"pilot";

    //'------------------------------------
    //' Payflow API Credentials 
    //'------------------------------------
    $API_User="xxxxx";
    //' Fill in the API_Password variable yourself, the wizard will not do this automatically
    $API_Password="xxxxx";
    $API_Vendor="xxxxx";
    $API_Partner="PayPal";


    // BN Code
    $sBNCode = "PF-CCWizard";

    /*  
    ' Define the PayPal Redirect URLs for Express Checkout
    '   This is the URL that the buyer is first sent to do authorize payment with their paypal account
    '   change the URL depending if you are testing on the sandbox or the live PayPal site
    '
    ' For the sandbox, the URL is https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    ' For the live site, the URL is https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=
    */

    if ($Env == "pilot") 
    {
        //$API_Endpoint = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com";
        $API_Endpoint = "https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com";
        $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }
    else
    {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://payflowpro.paypal.com";
        $PAYPAL_URL = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=";
    }



    $USE_PROXY = false;

    if (session_id() == "") 
        session_start();

    /* An express checkout transaction starts with a token, that
       identifies to PayPal your transaction
       In this example, when the script sees a token, the script
       knows that the buyer has already authorized payment through
       paypal.  If no token was found, the action is to send the buyer
       to PayPal to first authorize payment
       */

    /*   
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the shortcut implementation of SetExpressCheckout
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
    {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Construct the parameter string that describes SetExpressCheckout in the shortcut implementation

        $nvpstr = "&TENDER=P&ACTION=S";
        if ("Sale" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        elseif ("Authorization" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=A";
        }
        else //default to sale
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        $nvpstr .= "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr .= "&CURRENCY=" . $currencyCodeType;
        $nvpstr .= "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr .= "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;

        $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
        $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

        // Each part of Express Checkout must have a unique request ID.
        $unique_id = generateGUID();

        //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //' Make the API call to Payflow
        //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray = hash_call($nvpstr,$unique_id);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["RESULT"]);
        if($ack=="0")
        {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
        }

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*   
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for the mark implementation of SetExpressCheckout
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       currencyCodeType:   Currency code value the PayPal API
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order or Authorization
    '       returnURL:          the page where buyers return to after they are done with the payment review on PayPal
    '       cancelURL:          the page where buyers return to when they cancel the payment review on PayPal
    '       shipToName:         the Ship to name entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet:       the Ship to Street entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCity:         the Ship to City entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToState:        the Ship to State entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToCountryCode:  the Code for Ship to Country entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToZip:          the Ship to ZipCode entered on the merchant's site
    '       shipToStreet2:      the Ship to Street2 entered on the merchant's site
    '       phoneNum:           the phoneNum  entered on the merchant's site
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function CallMarkExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, 
                                      $cancelURL, $shipToName, $shipToStreet, $shipToCity, $shipToState,
                                      $shipToCountryCode, $shipToZip, $shipToStreet2, $phoneNum
                                    ) 
    {
        //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Construct the parameter string that describes SetExpressCheckout in the mark implementation

        $nvpstr = "&TENDER=P&ACTION=S";
        if ("Sale" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        elseif ("Authorization" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=A";
        }
        else //default to sale
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        $nvpstr .= "&AMT=" . $paymentAmount;
        $nvpstr .= "&CURRENCY=" . $currencyCodeType;
        $nvpstr .= "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
        $nvpstr .= "&RETURNURL" . $returnURL;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOSTREET=" . $shipToStreet;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $shipToStreet2;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOCITY=" . $shipToCity;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOSTATE=" . $shipToState;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=" . $shipToCountryCode;
        $nvpstr .= "&SHIPTOZIP=" . $shipToZip;
        $nvpstr .= "&ADDROVERRIDE=1";   // address override

        $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
        $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

        // Each part of Express Checkout must have a unique request ID.
        $unique_id = generateGUID();

        //'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
        //' Make the API call to Payflow
        //' If the API call succeded, then redirect the buyer to PayPal to begin to authorize payment.  
        //' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray = hash_call($nvpstr,$unique_id);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["RESULT"]);
        if($ack=="0")
        {
            $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
            $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
        }

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for GetExpressCheckoutDetails.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       None
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails response.
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function GetShippingDetails( $token )
    {
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------
        //' At this point, the buyer has completed authorizing the payment
        //' through Payflow.  The function will call Payflow to obtain the details
        //' of the authorization, incuding any shipping information of the
        //' buyer.  Remember, the authorization is not a completed transaction
        //' at this state - the buyer still needs an additional step to finalize
        //' the transaction
        //'--------------------------------------------------------------

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Build a second API request to Payflow, using the token as the
        //'  ID to get the details on the payment authorization
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $paymentType = $_SESSION['paymentType'];
        $nvpstr = "&TOKEN=" . $token . "&TENDER=P&ACTION=G";
        if ("Sale" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        elseif ("Authorization" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=A";
        }
        else //default to sale
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }

        // Each part of Express Checkout must have a unique request ID.
        $unique_id = generateGUID();

        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //' Make the API call and store the results in an array.  
        //' If the call was a success, show the authorization details, and provide
        //'     an action to complete the payment.  
        //' If failed, show the error
        //'---------------------------------------------------------------------------
        $resArray = hash_call($nvpstr,$unique_id);
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["RESULT"]);
        if($ack == "0")
        {   
            $_SESSION['payer_id'] = $resArray['PAYERID'];
        } 
        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for DoExpressCheckoutPayment.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       FinalPaymentAmt - the total transaction amount.
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the DoExpressCheckoutPayment response.
    ' Note:
    '       There are other optional parameters that can be passed to DoExpressCheckoutPayment that are not used here.
    '       See Table 7.6 in http://www.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/PayflowPro_Guide.pdf for details on the optional parameters.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function ConfirmPayment( $FinalPaymentAmt )
    {
        /* Gather the information to make the final call to
           finalize the PayPal payment.  The variable nvpstr
           holds the name value pairs
           */

        //Format the other parameters that were stored in the session from the previous calls   
        $token              = $_SESSION['token'];
        $paymentType        = $_SESSION['paymentType'];
        $currencyCodeType   = $_SESSION['currencyCodeType'];
        $payerID            = $_SESSION['payer_id'];

        $serverName         = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        $nvpstr = "&TENDER=P&ACTION=D";
        if ("Sale" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        elseif ("Authorization" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=A";
        }
        else //default to sale
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }

        $nvpstr .= "&TOKEN=" . $token . "&PAYERID=" . $payerID . "&AMT=" . $FinalPaymentAmt;
        $nvpstr .= '&CURRENCY=' . $currencyCodeType . '&IPADDRESS=' . $serverName;

        // Each part of Express Checkout must have a unique request ID.
        // Save it as a session variable in order to avoid duplication
        $unique_id = isset($_SESSION['unique_id']) ? $_SESSION['unique_id'] : generateGUID();
        $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $unique_id;

         /* Make the call to PayPal to finalize payment
            If an error occured, show the resulting errors
            */
        $resArray = hash_call($nvpstr,$unique_id);

        /* Display the API response back to the browser.
           If the response from PayPal was a success, display the response parameters'
           If the response was an error, display the errors received using APIError.php.
           */
        $ack = strtoupper($resArray["RESULT"]);

        return $resArray;
    }

    /*
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:  Prepares the parameters for direct payment (credit card) and makes the call.
    '
    ' Inputs:  
    '       paymentType:        paymentType has to be one of the following values: Sale or Order
    '       paymentAmount:      Total value of the shopping cart
    '       creditCardType      Credit card type has to one of the following values: Visa or MasterCard or Discover or Amex or Switch or Solo 
    '       creditCardNumber    Credit card number
    '       expDate             Credit expiration date
    '       cvv2                CVV2
    '       firstName           Customer's First Name
    '       lastName            Customer's Last Name
    '       street              Customer's Street Address
    '       city                Customer's City
    '       state               Customer's State                
    '       zip                 Customer's Zip                  
    '       countryCode         Customer's Country represented as a PayPal CountryCode
    '       currencyCode        Customer's Currency represented as a PayPal CurrencyCode
    '       orderdescription    Short textual description of the order
    '
    ' Note:
    '       There are other optional inputs for credit card processing that are not presented here.
    '       For a complete list of inputs available, please see the documentation here for US and UK:
    '       http://www.paypal.com/en_US/pdf/PayflowPro_Guide.pdf
    '       https://www.paypal.com/en_GB/pdf/PP_WebsitePaymentsPro_IntegrationGuide.pdf
    '       
    ' Returns: 
    '       The NVP Collection object of the Response.
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------   
    */
    function DirectPayment( $paymentType, $paymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber, $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $countryCode, $currencyCode, $orderdescription )
    {
        // Construct the parameter string that describes the credit card payment
        $replaceme = array("-", " ");
        $card_num = str_replace($replaceme,"",$creditCardNumber);


        $nvpstr = "&TENDER=C";
        if ("Sale" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }
        elseif ("Authorization" == $paymentType)
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=A";
        }
        else //default to sale
        {
            $nvpstr .= "&TRXTYPE=S";
        }

        // Other information
        $ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


        $nvpstr .= '&ACCT='.$card_num.'&CVV2='.$cvv2.'&EXPDATE='.$expDate.'&ACCTTYPE='.$creditCardType.'&AMT='.$paymentAmount.'&CURRENCY='.$currencyCode;
        $nvpstr .= '&FIRSTNAME='.$firstName.'&LASTNAME='.$lastName.'&STREET='.$street.'&CITY='.$city.'&STATE='.$state.'&ZIP='.$zip.'&COUNTRY='.$countryCode;
        $nvpstr .= '&CLIENTIP='. $ipaddr . '&ORDERDESC=' . $orderdescription;
        // Transaction results (especially values for declines and error conditions) returned by each PayPal-supported
        // processor vary in detail level and in format. The Payflow Verbosity parameter enables you to control the kind
        // and level of information you want returned. 
        // By default, Verbosity is set to LOW. A LOW setting causes PayPal to normalize the transaction result values. 
        // Normalizing the values limits them to a standardized set of values and simplifies the process of integrating 
        // the Payflow SDK.
        // By setting Verbosity to MEDIUM, you can view the processor's raw response values. This setting is more “verbose”
        // than the LOW setting in that it returns more detailed, processor-specific information. 
        // Review the chapter in the Developer's Guides regarding VERBOSITY and the INQUIRY function for more details.
        // Set the transaction verbosity to MEDIUM.
        $nvpstr .= '&VERBOSITY=MEDIUM';

        // The $unique_id field is storing our unique id that we'll use in the request id header.



//      $unique_id = date('ymd-H').rand(1000,9999);     
        $unique_id = time().rand(1000, 9999);       
        /*'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Make the call to Payflow to finalize payment
        ' If an error occured, show the resulting errors
        '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $resArray = hash_call($nvpstr,$unique_id);

        return $resArray;
    }

    /**
      '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      * hash_call: Function to perform the API call to Payflow
      * @nvpStr is nvp string.
      * returns an associtive array containing the response from the server.
      '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function hash_call($nvpStr,$unique_id)
    {
        //declaring of global variables
        global $API_Endpoint, $API_User, $API_Password, $API_Vendor, $API_Partner;
        global $USE_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST, $PROXY_PORT;
        global $gv_ApiErrorURL;
        global $sBNCode;

        $len = strlen($nvpStr);
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: text/namevalue";
        // Set the server timeout value to 45, but notice below in the cURL section, the timeout
        // for cURL is set to 90 seconds.  Make sure the server timeout is less than the connection.
        $headers[] = "X-VPS-CLIENT-TIMEOUT: 45";
        $headers[] = "X-VPS-REQUEST-ID:" . $unique_id;

        //setting the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        //turning off the server and peer verification(TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 90);      // times out after 90 secs
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        //if USE_PROXY constant set to TRUE in Constants.php, then only proxy will be enabled.
        //Set proxy name to PROXY_HOST and port number to PROXY_PORT in constants.php 
        if($USE_PROXY)
            curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $PROXY_HOST. ":" . $PROXY_PORT); 

        //NVPRequest for submitting to server
        $nvpreq = "USER=".$API_User.'&VENDOR='.$API_Vendor.'&PARTNER='.$API_Partner.'&PWD='.$API_Password . $nvpStr . "&BUTTONSOURCE=" . urlencode($sBNCode);

        //setting the nvpreq as POST FIELD to curl
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        //getting response from server
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        //convrting NVPResponse to an Associative Array
        $nvpResArray=deformatNVP($response);
        $nvpReqArray=deformatNVP($nvpreq);
        $_SESSION['nvpReqArray']=$nvpReqArray;

        if (curl_errno($ch)) 
        {
            // moving to display page to display curl errors
              $_SESSION['curl_error_no']=curl_errno($ch) ;
              $_SESSION['curl_error_msg']=curl_error($ch);

              //Execute the Error handling module to display errors. 
        } 
        else 
        {
             //closing the curl
            curl_close($ch);
        }

        return $nvpResArray;
    }

    /*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     Purpose: Redirects to PayPal.com site.
     Inputs:  NVP string.
     Returns: 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    function RedirectToPayPal ( $token )
    {
        global $PAYPAL_URL;

        // Redirect to paypal.com here
        $payPalURL = $PAYPAL_URL . $token;
        header("Location: ".$payPalURL);
        exit;
    }


    /*'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     * This function will take NVPString and convert it to an Associative Array and it will decode the response.
      * It is usefull to search for a particular key and displaying arrays.
      * @nvpstr is NVPString.
      * @nvpArray is Associative Array.
       ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      */
    function deformatNVP($nvpstr)
    {
        $intial=0;
        $nvpArray = array();

        while(strlen($nvpstr))
        {
            //postion of Key
            $keypos= strpos($nvpstr,'=');
            //position of value
            $valuepos = strpos($nvpstr,'&') ? strpos($nvpstr,'&'): strlen($nvpstr);

            /*getting the Key and Value values and storing in a Associative Array*/
            $keyval=substr($nvpstr,$intial,$keypos);
            $valval=substr($nvpstr,$keypos+1,$valuepos-$keypos-1);
            //decoding the respose
            $nvpArray[urldecode($keyval)] =urldecode( $valval);
            $nvpstr=substr($nvpstr,$valuepos+1,strlen($nvpstr));
         }
        return $nvpArray;
    }

    function generateCharacter () {
        $possible = "1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
        return $char;
    }

    function generateGUID () {
        $GUID = generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter()."-";
        $GUID = $GUID .generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter()."-";
        $GUID = $GUID .generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter()."-";
        $GUID = $GUID .generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter()."-";
        $GUID = $GUID .generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter().generateCharacter();
        return $GUID;
    }

?>
```

Here is the code where I can set credit card information from the buyer

```
<?php
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo 'start';

    /*==================================================================
     Payflow Direct Payment Call
     ===================================================================
    */
require_once ("paypalfunctions.php");

$PaymentOption = "Visa";
if ( $PaymentOption == "Visa" || $PaymentOption == "MasterCard" || $PaymentOption == "Amex" || $PaymentOption == "Discover" )
{
    /*
    '------------------------------------
    ' The paymentAmount is the total value of 
    ' the shopping cart, that was set 
    ' earlier in a session variable 
    ' by the shopping cart page
    '------------------------------------
    */

    $finalPaymentAmount =  "0.1";

    $creditCardType     = "VISA"; //' Set this to one of the acceptable values (Visa/MasterCard/Amex/Discover) match it to what was selected on your Billing page
    $creditCardNumber   = "4032039997933975"; // ' Set this to the string entered as the credit card number on the Billing page
    $expDate            = "0620"; // ' Set this to the credit card expiry date entered on the Billing page
    $cvv2               = ""; // ' Set this to the CVV2 string entered on the Billing page 
    $firstName          = "test"; // ' Set this to the customer's first name that was entered on the Billing page 
    $lastName           = "user"; // ' Set this to the customer's last name that was entered on the Billing page 
    $street             = "street"; // ' Set this to the customer's street address that was entered on the Billing page 
    $city               = "city"; // ' Set this to the customer's city that was entered on the Billing page 
    $state              = "state"; // ' Set this to the customer's state that was entered on the Billing page 
    $zip                = "2000"; // ' Set this to the zip code of the customer's address that was entered on the Billing page 
    $countryCode        = "US"; // ' Set this to the PayPal code for the Country of the customer's address that was entered on the Billing page 
    $currencyCode       = "USD"; // ' Set this to the PayPal code for the Currency used by the customer
    $orderDescription   = "sample sales"; // ' Set this to the textual description of this order 

    $paymentType            = "Sale";

    /*
    '------------------------------------
    '
    ' The DirectPayment function is defined in the file PayPalFunctions.php,
    ' that is included at the top of this file.
    '-------------------------------------------------
    */
    $resArray = DirectPayment ( $paymentType, $finalPaymentAmount, $creditCardType, $creditCardNumber, $expDate, $cvv2, $firstName, $lastName, $street, $city, $state, $zip, $countryCode, $currencyCode, $orderDescription );

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($resArray);
    echo '</pre>';
    $ack = $resArray["RESULT"];
    if( $ack != "0" ) 
    {
        // See pages 50 through 65 in https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_PayflowPro_Guide.pdf for a list of RESULT values (error codes)
        //Display a user friendly Error on the page using any of the following error information returned by Payflow
        $ErrorCode = $ack;
        $ErrorMsg = $resArray["RESPMSG"];

        echo "Credit Card transaction failed. ";
        echo "Error Message: " . $ErrorMsg;
        echo "Error Code: " . $ErrorCode;
    }
}       

echo 'done';

?>
```

Credit card information came from sandbox accounts.

Note: I already setup the sandbox email address from my paypal manager account by following this guide https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/929/

Comment: Please show us your code and what you've already tried.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?